# Rendering math in offline copy of a website

Tags: math, render, offline, mathjax

My internet connection is really sketchy where I live, so I downloaded this website. The website is a question bank for all of my classes. It is really helpful so have it offline so I used a program called HTTRack to mirror the website to my desktop. Most of the questions I need are math and science based, so the code for the website has a lot of rendered math.

The problem is, the math isn't rendering in my offline copy. The math seems to render fine in the online version here: https://www.ibdocuments.com/IB%20QUESTIONBANKS/4.%20Fourth%20Edition/questionbank.ibo.org/en/teachers/00000/questionbanks/7-dp-mathematics-hl/questions/4504.html, but I don't know why I am unable to render it as well. I would've been able to solve it if I had the knowledge to code with these, but this is all very new to me and I have never worked with web files before.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

[image: This is what it looks like when I open my offline copy:]

Comment: The website uses a third party library "MathJax" to render the equations. Third party means it's provided by another website, which might be why HTTRack didn't retrieve it.

Comment: The relevant section of the webpage is `<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML-full" async></script>`. If this is still present as-is in your copy of the website, I would assume it would properly work if you had internet connectivity. To have it work offline, retrieve a copy of the library and change the `<script` tag to refer to it

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow. Could you please tell me how to retrieve the library to install it and where I would have to change the code? Since there are thousands of questions for the topics, would I have to make the same code change to all those websites?

Comment: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML-full` is an URL which will serve the MathJax library configured as the website requires it when accessed. When online, it works fine and makes the website display equations fancily. You could access the URL yourself, which would give you a copy of the library you could use in your offline copy of the website. The simplest option would indeed be to edit every page which needs that library to point to your local copy. Tools could help replacing that `script` tag in every .html page in a directory

Comment: Another alternative would be to have a local HTTP server serve the library and use your hosts file to tell your computer "when looking for cdnjs.cloudflare.com, check at 127.0.0.1" which would make it look for the third party library on your own local HTTP server. But I'm sure that'd be much work than doing a mass search/replace on all the webpages